# mysqladmin Access Denied when using -defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqladmin

While using `mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`, mysqladmin fails with following error:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

But if I try to login using username and password like: `mysqladmin -uroot -pmysupersecretpass` it works.

Contains of `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = mysupersecretpass
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = mysupersecretpass
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

However I am also able login using `mysql -u root -p`.

can anyone tell me what's wrong with `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`?

Comment: You are providing the setting `host` and `socket` at the same time, which doesn't make sense. What error messages do you get when you use `mysqladmin -h localhost -uroot -pmysupersecretpass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add doublequotes around your password.:
`password="mysecretpw"`

Without double quotes it wouldn't be possible to read special chars in your password.